# Why passing p=3+3 by GET results in 3 3 and by POST is 3+3?

Tags: php, html, forms, post, get

Basically that is the question, when I send the same parameter by different methods I get different values.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because `+` is the URL encoding of the space character in HTTP. When you use `GET`, the URL is parsed by the server before the data are handed to your code. The processing for `POST` is different and doesn't include that conversion of `+` to space.

If you want to actually send a `+` as data in a `GET`, encode it as `%2B`. The same decoding process that converts `+` to space will convert `%2B` to a `+`. Also take a look at the [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) function.